# How do I forward an email, including the original forwarded message and sender email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out how we can forward the original message and include the recipient email, full chain, so for example:

```
---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: Ram Sam <test@example.org>
Date: Mon, Apr 4, 2022 at 5:42 PM
Subject: RE: about nurse appreciation day
To: receiver@example.com <receiver@example.com>


Receiver-

Sure, that sounds great! Also, share any flyers, brochures, etc. We do currently use

reward programs and this may be similar.
 

Thank you,

 

Ram Sam, PHR, SHRM-CP, FLWCS| Vice President of X

2033 Main St, Address| X Healthcare Management, LLC
```

I am also labeling the ones that were forwarded so they don't get reforwarded on the second run. Here is what I have so far

```
function Forward() {
  var imessagesForwarded = 0;
  var label = 'LeadTest';
  var doneLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('LeadFinished');
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();

  var iforwarded = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var it = threads.length;
    if (iforwarded == im ) {
      threads[i-1].addLabel(doneLabel);
      threads[i-1].removeLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label));
    }
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    var im = messages.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {  
      var email = messages[j];
      if (!email.isStarred()) { //To keep track of processed emails, I star message when processed.
        try {
          forwardTo = 'alex@hypernovamarketing.com';
          email.forward(forwardTo, {replyTo: email.getFrom(),subject: email.getSubject()});
    messages[m].forward(rtm_email,{htmlBody: emailoptions + body , Attachment: attachment});
          imessagesForwarded++;
          email.star();
          iforwarded++;
        } catch(e) {
          MailApp.sendEmail("alex@hypernovamarketing.com","Forward failed", "Errormsg:\n" + e.message);
          continue;
        }
      } else { 
        iforwarded++;
      }
    }
  }  
  if (iforwarded == im ) {
    threads[i-1].addLabel(doneLabel);
    threads[i-1].removeLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Well, statement of the obvious... the `IF` statement in lines#11-14 references the variable `im`. But `im` isn't declared until line#16. Better to move rows#15-16 above the `IF`. so that you have a value for `im`.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user five times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function Forward() {
  
  // create variables for label names and get/create labels
  var labelName = 'LeadTest' //'LeadTest'
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName) || GmailApp.createLabel(labelName)

  var doneLabelName = "LeadFinished" // 'LeadFinished'
  var doneLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(doneLabelName) || GmailApp.createLabel(doneLabelName)
  
  //get all the threads containing the labelName
  var threads = label.getThreads()
  var tLen = threads.length
  
  // loop through the threads
  for (var t = 0; t < tLen; t++) {
    
    Logger .log("DEBUG: Thread status: t:"+t+" of "+tLen)    

    // get the messages for this thread
    var messages = threads[t].getMessages();
    var mLen = messages.length;
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#"+t+" -Number of messages (mLen) = "+mLen)  

    // loop through messages in this thread
    for (var m = 0; m < mLen; m++) {

      var email = messages[m]
      
      //To keep track of processed emails, I star message when processed.
      // test if this message is NOT starred
      if (!email.isStarred()) { 

        // this message is NOT starred-forward the email
         forwardTo = 'alex@hypernovamarketing.com'
        
        email.forward(
            forwardTo, 
            {replyTo: email.getFrom(),
            subject: emaiul.getSubject()})
        
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#"+t+", message#"+m+" -Email forwarded")
        
        // star this message
        email.star()
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#"+t+", message#"+m+" -Star message")

      } else { 
        
        // this message IS starred, so do nothing 
        // DEBUG: Left this "ELSE" for the sake of completeness/clarity
        
      }

    } // end of message loop


    // for all messages in this thread
    // delete 'Test' label and relace with 'Done' label
    threads[t].addLabel(doneLabel)
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#"+t+", `done` label added to thread")
    threads[t].removeLabel(label)
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Thread#"+t+",`test` label removed from thread")
    
  
  }  // end of threads loop
 
}
```

---

**Comments**

- the label names are defined
- each label is defined as either `getUserLabelByName()` or  `createLabel`. This will stops the error message `Exception: Invalid argument: label`
- neither of the variables (`iforwarded` or `imessagesForwarded`) are required.
- the variables for threads loop (`t`) and messages loop (`m`) were changed so that they were more intuitive
- your code was sending forwarding each email twice.
- the code to remove the 'test' label and add the 'Done' label is moved to follow the message loop WITHIN each thread.
- the logic statement `if (iforwarded == im )` is unnecessary this is the default outcome at the end of the messages loop.
- I deleted the `try/catch` code since it complicated the logic flow/sequence. You can add it back now that the sequence is more clear.